# How to remove/replace any string from a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame including 950 rows and 204 columns, and I want to find and replace any possible string from this dataframe. When it is only one column I can simply do that through 2 lines code below:

```
 for i in df['name of column']:
     df[i].replace(r'^([A-Za-z]|[0-9]|_)+$', np.NaN, regex=True,inplace=True)
```

but now when it is more than 200 columns, how can I do that?
Every help is appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at [Series.str.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) and iterate over your columns replacing as you go

Comment: @G.Anderson : see the answer by *Guru Stron* explaining why you shouldn't iterate over rows or columns at all when replacing. Just use .replace() on columns or on entire DataFrame instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When it is only one column I can simply do that through 2 lines code below: ...

But you better should not - iterating dataframe can affect performance negatively (though currently you don't have that much data).

Just use `replace` on dataframe itself:

```py
df = df.replace(r'^([A-Za-z]|[0-9]|_)+$', np.NaN, regex=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer which also learned me sth new. But I again face the problem of existing a string `ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''
`. Actually the work that I am doing is using **from sklearn.feature_selection import RFE** and for this I run `rfe.fit(x, y)` but it throw the error above.